# How can I search people on Facebook by name and by year?

Tags: facebook, search

I found out how to search by year range (https://www.facebook.com/search/25/30/users-age-2) - it shows people 25-30 years old.

But how to add to this link full name (name / last-name)?

Comment: So you want to be able to search people 25-30 years old with a specific name (i.e. "John Smith")?

Comment: @freginold yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SearchIsBack.com](https://searchisback.com/) has put together an advanced search interface for Facebook which does multifactor searches like that. By examining the search parameters they use, you can discover Facebook's pattern.

To search for a person by name and age, you would use this format:

`https://www.facebook.com/search/1993/before/users-born/1986/after/users-born/str/john%20smith/users-named/intersect/`

The above search query will return users named "John Smith" (or some semblance of that name) who were born after 1986 and before 1993.

**Some notes for doing an advanced Facebook search this way:**

- The years you specify are exclusive; meaning that someone born in 1986 or 1993 won't be included in the search results.
- Be sure to include an escaped space (`%20`) between the first and last names.